# Spring Cloud Gateway Exceeded limit on max bytes to buffer : 262144 Error

Tags: java, spring-boot, filter, spring-cloud-gateway

I am using Spring boot 2.5.3 and spring cloud 2020.0.3 and facing this issue. I tried the below in yml file.

```
spring:
  codec:
    max-in-memory-size: 15MB
```

Tried adding the configuration bean.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFlux
public class WebFluxWebConfig implements WebFluxConfigurer
{
    @Override
    public void configureHttpMessageCodecs(ServerCodecConfigurer configurer) {
    configurer.defaultCodecs().maxInMemorySize(16 * 1024 * 1024);
    }

}
```

Below is my filter class.

```
@Component
public class GenericModifyRequestFilter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory<GenericModifyRequestFilter.Config>
{
        
    @Autowired
    Util util;
    
    public GenericModifyRequestFilter() 
    {
        super(Config.class);
    }
    
    @Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Config config) 
    {
        String uniqueID = UUID.randomUUID().toString().replace("-","").toUpperCase();
                 try 
            {
                X509Certificate[] certs = exchange.getRequest().getSslInfo().getPeerCertificates();             
                certString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString( certs[0].getEncoded() );               
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            {
                logger.error(logid+"Exception in reading certificate from client request:"+e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        return (exchange, chain) -> 
        {   
            exchange.getRequest().mutate()
            .header("Certificate", certString)
            .header("Accept", "application/xml")
            .header("UniqueID", uniqueID)            
            .build();
            
            
            ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory.Config modifyRequestConfig = new ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory.Config()                   
                    .setRewriteFunction(String.class, String.class, (exchange1, originalRequestBody) -> 
                    {                       
                        String modifiedRequestBody = util.modifyRequestBody(originalRequestBody,uniqueID,logid); 
                        return Mono.just(modifiedRequestBody);
                    }) ;            
                            
            return new ModifyRequestBodyGatewayFilterFactory()          
                    .apply(modifyRequestConfig)             
                    .filter(exchange, chain)
                    .then(Mono.fromRunnable(() -> 
                    {
                          logger.info(logid+"Responded back to client");    
                    }));
        };
    }
    
    
    public static class Config 
    {
        
    }
```

Could you please let me know what is being missed? or this issue is resolved in any specific version of spring cloud/spring boot?

Below is the error stack:

```
org.springframework.core.io.buffer.DataBufferLimitException: Exceeded limit on max bytes to buffer : 262144
    at org.springframework.core.io.buffer.LimitedDataBufferList.raiseLimitException(LimitedDataBufferList.java:98) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_ checkpoint ? org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
    |_ checkpoint ? HTTP POST "/FileTransfer" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Stack trace:
        at org.springframework.core.io.buffer.LimitedDataBufferList.raiseLimitException(LimitedDataBufferList.java:98) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.core.io.buffer.LimitedDataBufferList.updateCount(LimitedDataBufferList.java:91) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at org.springframework.core.io.buffer.LimitedDataBufferList.add(LimitedDataBufferList.java:57) ~[spring-core-5.3.9.jar!/:5.3.9]
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollect$CollectSubscriber.onNext(MonoCollect.java:118) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar!/:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar!/:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:200) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar!/:3.4.8]
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:120) ~[reactor-core-3.4.8.jar!/:3.4.8]
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:364) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.9.jar!/:1.0.9]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:404) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.9.jar!/:1.0.9]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpServerOperations.onInboundNext(HttpServerOperations.java:542) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.9.jar!/:1.0.9]
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:93) ~[reactor-netty-core-1.0.9.jar!/:1.0.9]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at reactor.netty.http.server.HttpTrafficHandler.channelRead(HttpTrafficHandler.java:252) ~[reactor-netty-http-1.0.9.jar!/:1.0.9]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler$DelegatingChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:436) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) ~[netty-codec-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:311) ~[netty-codec-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:432) ~[netty-codec-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[netty-codec-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.channelRead(CombinedChannelDuplexHandler.java:251) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.unwrap(SslHandler.java:1374) ~[netty-handler-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decodeJdkCompatible(SslHandler.java:1237) ~[netty-handler-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1286) ~[netty-handler-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.decodeRemovalReentryProtection(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:507) ~[netty-codec-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:446) ~[netty-codec-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) ~[netty-codec-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) ~[netty-transport-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:795) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.66.Final-linux-x86_64.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:480) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.66.Final-linux-x86_64.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378) ~[netty-transport-native-epoll-4.1.66.Final-linux-x86_64.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.66.Final.jar!/:4.1.66.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
```

Comment: Hi Mohamed, did you find solution to this problem? are you using the same property now?

Comment: No, I did not find the solution yet. I moved the modify request body filter logic to the backend application.